# Group By ALL child records

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012

If I have the following data, where one rule can have multiple criteria:

```
-------------------
RuleId   CriteriaId
-------------------
1        1
1        2
1        3
2        1
2        2
2        3
3        1
3        2
```

How do I get *minimum* RuleId while grouping on ALL criteria for the rule. In other words, since rule 1 and 2 have exactly the same criteria, they would be in one group, but since rule 3 doesn't have the same criteria it would be in a different group.

I'm expecting to get back the following results:

```
-------------------
RuleId   CriteriaId
-------------------
1        1
1        2
1        3
3        1
3        2
```

Doing a straight GROUP BY with a MIN on RuleId isn't going to work here because that would give back this instead:

```
-------------------
RuleId   CriteriaId
-------------------
1        1
1        2
1        3
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data

```
create table rules (RuleId int, CriteriaId int);
insert into rules values
(1 ,1),
(1 ,2),
(1 ,3),
(2 ,1),
(2 ,2),
(2 ,3),
(3 ,1),
(3 ,2);
```

Your query

```
;with flattened as (
        select r.ruleid, (select ',' + rtrim(r2.criteriaid)
                            from rules r2
                           where r2.RuleId = r.RuleId
                        order by r2.criteriaid
                             for xml path(''), type).value('/','varchar(max)') list
        from rules r
    group by r.ruleid
)
  select r3.*
    from rules r3
    join (
         select min(ruleid) min_ruleid
           from flattened
       group by list) r4 on r4.min_ruleid = r3.ruleid
order by r3.ruleid, r3.CriteriaId;
```

Comment: Interesting. I wonder what the performance is compared to @Gordon's answer is.

Comment: Faster by my estimation. It's O(N^2) but the inner N (string concat) is on a subset only if you have a proper index on (ruleid, criteriaid). It is also 100% correct because it compares exact criteria id's in the set instead of just counting.

Comment: You're right. After we got some indexes in place, this was much faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the absolute best way to do it but it works.

```
CREATE TABLE GroupingTest (RuleId int, CriteriaId int)
INSERT INTO GroupingTest VALUES 
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 1),
    (3, 2)

----------------------------------------------------
WITH MergedGroupingCriteria AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT RuleId, 
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(CriteriaId AS varchar)
                FROM GroupingTest GT
                WHERE GT.RuleId = MergeGroup.RuleId
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)')
            , 1, 2, '') AS MergedGrouping
    FROM GroupingTest MergeGroup )
SELECT MIN(GroupingTest.RuleId), GroupingTest.CriteriaId
FROM GroupingTest
JOIN MergedGroupingCriteria
    ON GroupingTest.RuleId = MergedGroupingCriteria.RuleId
GROUP BY MergedGroupingCriteria.MergedGrouping, GroupingTest.CriteriaId
ORDER BY MIN(GroupingTest.RuleId), GroupingTest.CriteriaId
```

Answer (score 1):

Mine uses [SQL Server's `LISTAGG`/`GROUP_CONCAT` emulation](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1277):

```
SELECT MIN(list.ruleid) minrule, rules
FROM 
(SELECT RuleId,
stuff((
    SELECT ', ' + CriteriaId
    FROM Table1 as t1
    where t1.RuleId = t2.RuleId
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') Rules
FROM Table1 as t2
GROUP BY RuleId) list
GROUP BY Rules
ORDER BY minrule;
```

Here's **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a937a/12)**.

I assumed both fields as `varchar` and my result is still concatenated.

**EDIT**

The following query is free of assumptions and provides the right result format:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE RuleId IN

(SELECT MIN(list.ruleid) minrule
FROM 
(SELECT RuleId,
stuff((
    SELECT ', ' + CAST(CriteriaId AS varchar)
    FROM Table1 as t1
    where t1.RuleId = t2.RuleId
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') Rules
FROM Table1 as t2
GROUP BY RuleId) list
GROUP BY Rules)

ORDER BY RuleId
;
```

Updated **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0e6a/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.  This starts by creating a list of all pairs of rules that have exactly matching criteria.  Criteria match if there are the same number on each rule. And, when we count the number that match, the number of matches is the same as the total number.

The following query finds these pairs:

```
select driver.ruleid1, driver.ruleid2
from (select rc1.ruleid as ruleid1, rc2.ruleid as ruleid2,
             rc1.numCriteria as Num1, rc2.numCriteria as Num2
      from (select ruleid, COUNT(*) as numCriteria from rc group by ruleid) rc1 join
           (select ruleid, COUNT(*) as numCriteria from rc group by ruleid) rc2
           on rc1.ruleid <= rc2.ruleid and
              rc1.numCriteria = rc2.numCriteria
     ) driver left outer join
     rc rc1
     on driver.ruleid1 = rc1.ruleid left outer join
     rc rc2
     on rc2.ruleid = driver.ruleid2 and
        rc1.criteriaId = rc2.criteriaid
group by driver.ruleid1, driver.ruleid2
having max(driver.Num1) = COUNT(distinct rc1.ruleid) and
       MAX(driver.Num1) = COUNT(distinct rc2.ruleId)
```

The `driver` subquery does a first pass, getting all rule pairs with the same number of criteria.  Then the criteria are joined in.  I realize this creates a little cartesian product.  But, to count the number of criteria, the query uses `count(distinct)`.

To assign a unique group id, just take the minimum of rule1.  Something like this:

```
with pairs as (
      <above subquery>
     )
select ruleid2, min(ruleid1) as groupnum
from pairs
group by ruleid2
```

Comment: It'll take a while for me to get my head around that query, but what happens if two rules each have 3 criteria but only one of those criteria match between the two rules? Would this query give a false positive or does it handle that scenario ok?

Comment: @adam0101 . . . The `driver` table will give a "false" positive.  But then the number of matching criteria are counted on each side.  That is the purpose of the additional joins, `group by`, and `having` clause.